# How to Get Refresh Token and ad more Scope in MSAL

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to access refressh token and adding more scope in login outlook using MSAL. Need both scope in request offline_access and openid.

```
- (void)signInUser:(void (^)(MSALUser *user, NSString *token, NSError *error))signInBlock
{
    MSALPublicClientApplication *application = [self createClientApplication];

    [application acquireTokenForScopes:@[@"User.Read", @"Calendars.Read"]
                       completionBlock:^(MSALResult *result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (error)
        {
            signInBlock(nil, nil, error);
            return;
        }

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:user.userIdentifier forKey:CURRENT_USER_KEY];

        signInBlock(user, result.accessToken, error);
    }];
}
```